# Laravel handing requests concurrently

Tags: php, api, laravel

I currently have an API written in Laravel (PHP). We are serving about 2 requests a second and it works fine, but when this increases to 4/10 a second during peak time, the API hangs and doesn't begin processing requests until it has finished resolving the others.

I have a redis queue set up but I suspect that is too late in picking the request up, does anyone have any ideas how the server can deal with requests concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

In laravel you can use [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues)

I think it can help you process your requests concurrent.